# what is the proper way to use the adjective "calm"

Tags: word-choice

Do we say "in calm", "on calm", or just "calm"? For example:

> *I am writing **in** calm*
>    or
>    *I am writing **on** calm*

Comment: Neither of those options make sense. Do you want to say "I am calmly writing"?

Comment: This question may be migrated to [ell.se]

Comment: No I just want to use only the word calm

Comment: *As I write this, I am calm.* (calm is an adjective). *As I sit here, I am calmly writing this.* (calmly is an adverb).  *Stay calm!* (adjective)  Walk calmly!  (adverb)

Comment: So it makes no sense to just say in calm alone?

Comment: *In calm water,* *in calm weather,* *in a state of calm,* but no, I can't think of *in calm* alone.

Comment: *In calm* (calm is a noun): *She lived in calm all the days of her life.*

Comment: @Amir - Not when you're talking about writing. [Have a look](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=writing+calmly%2C+calmly+writing%2C+writing+in+calm&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwriting%20calmly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccalmly%20writing%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no obvious grammatical or syntactic reason why we don't say *"I'm writing this in calm"*.

As @CarSmack points out, *"She lived in calm all the days of her life"* is perhaps more acceptable. But idiomatically, *"She lived in **tranquility** all the days of her life"*, for example, is far more likely.

To describe your overall state, use adjectival *"I **am calm** as/while I write"*. To associate the state more closely with the action of the verb, use adverbial *"I **am calmly writing**"* (or *"I am **writing calmly**"*).

Comment: Tranquility works much better than calm, but the statement is still ambiguous. Is the writer writing in a tranquil state of mind, in tranquil surroundings, or both?

Comment: I never explicitly tried to couple *write* and *tranquil*, so that potential ambiguity doesn't arise in the context of my answer. Let's face it, few native speakers would be likely to come out with *"I'm tranquilly writing"* - it's English, @Jim, but not as we know it.

Comment: My apologies. I was referring to the ambiguity of the original statement, not to your answer.